# Track visits with embed code

Tags: javascript, laravel

I have an embed code:

```
<div id="lfc598438abae8b2" class="lf-container" lf-include-html="https://s3.amazonaws.com/leadformlyimages/form/39246.html" data-token="POuG8EIhbpdHUWZNosZYwOJmqXBadeAEuR9Hsw6t+39246" data-embed-type="simple" lf-elements="2"></div><script type="text/javascript">if(document.getElementById("lf-load-scripts")==null){var s = document.createElement("script");s.id="lf-load-scripts";s.type = "text/javascript";s.src = "//d2erq0e4xljvr7.cloudfront.net/assets/js/leadformly-embed_advance.min.js";document.body.appendChild(s);}</script>
```

Example Embed on jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/zfr8jbj7/

This code produces forms from S3 and cloudfront. I need to track the number of times this form is visited. So, for ex. I embed this code in a website - example.com.

So, the number of times people visit example.com needs to be tracked.

I tried adding an AJAX request in the javascript, but it gives cross origin issue.

Is there a way I can get number of visits from S3? Or some way to call API or Laravel end point to increase the count of form through javascript?

Comment: Add some code where you call the (blade) where you include the div.

Comment: I'm storing the entire HTML on S3, so no blade is being called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Domain1: add code `<img src="http://domain2.com/track">`

Domain2: add route `Route::get('/track', 'IndexController@track')->name('track');`

And action:

```
public function track(Request $request) {
    // increase stored number here

    header('Content-Type: image/gif');
    return base64_decode('R0lGODlhAQABAJAAAP8AAAAAACH5BAUQAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICBAEAOw==');
}
```

Images don't need to be of the same domain.

Comment: This is AWESOME! Thanks.